# I want to add forEach so that I can active each & everydiv separately

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, foreach

I have a section & it's reaction section with love, comment & share option. so I want to add toggle Class whenever I click on love button or comment button and I make it

[image]

but the problem is I copy this section for multiple time then it's not work, I use try to use foreach, but it's not work.
I want it link no matter how many same section on my page, if I click any of this button, the toggle things work

**this is the code I use , it's the HTML code**

**this is the code**

```js
document.querySelector(".lverct").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".lverct").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".cmnt").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".cmnt").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".Share").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".Share").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".lverct1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".lverct1").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".cmnt1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".cmnt1").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".Share1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".Share1").classList.toggle("kp");
});
```

```css
.pstfeedbackbtn{
margin:10px 20px;
display:flex;
gap:10px;
}
.dflx{
cursor:pointer;
}

.lverct.kp button{
background:crimson;
}
.lverct1.kp button{
background:crimson;
}


.cmnt.kp button{
background:green;
}
.cmnt1.kp button{
background:green;
}


.Share.kp button{
background:orange;
}
.Share1.kp button{
background:orange;
}
```

```html
                    <div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
                      <div class="dflx lverct ">
                        <button>Like</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx cmnt ">
                        <button>Comment</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx Share ">
                       <button>Share</button>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
                      <div class="dflx lverct lverct1">
                       <button>Like</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx cmnt cmnt1">
                         <button>Comment</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx Share Share1">
                      <button>Share</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

**I don't want to make it like this, I want to make it like a for-each functionality so that no matter how many same section I have, I'll work for everyone**

Comment: In the demo you provided the toggle is working!

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of adding several event listeners — it’s more maintainable and applies to dynamically added elements. See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [this Q&A](/q/1687296/4642212). Note that `".lverct, .cmnt, .Share, .lverct1, .cmnt1, .Share1"` is the selector for all your elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all three button types with the selector `.dflx > button` in a `querySelectorAll`, then loop through them and use `e.target.parentElement` to get the div to toggle the class on.

Since you're now attaching the click events to `button`, `e.target.parentElement` will always find the `.dflx` div, as long as the HTML structure doesn't change (see event bubbling and capturing). It's in my opinion a little cleaner since the button element is what the user is intending to click:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dflx > button")).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("kp");
  });
});
```

```css
.pstfeedbackbtn {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.dflx {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lverct.kp button {
  background: crimson;
}

.cmnt.kp button {
  background: green;
}

.Share.kp button {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
  <div class="dflx lverct ">
    <button>Like</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx cmnt ">
    <button>Comment</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx Share ">
    <button>Share</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
  <div class="dflx lverct lverct1">
    <button>Like</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx cmnt cmnt1">
    <button>Comment</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx Share Share1">
    <button>Share</button>
  </div>
</div>
```